# Android Studio see whole LogCat log

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

Is there any way of seeing the full logcat log? I have an error in my app but I don't have time to see it because lots of text appears after the error and goes past the limit of lines in the logcat. So even if I go to the top the error is already gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the filter in Android Studio. Here are some options you have:

1. Limit the output only to your app:

[image]

2. Limit the output only to error messages:

[image]

3. Add custom TAG to the place where the error is thrown and filter by that:

   `Log.e(custom_tag, message, throwable);`

Also, if you don't want the logcat to be scrolled automatically, just select a piece of output in the middle (or scroll up).

Comment: Everytime my program runs, there is a huge logcat generated and after sometime a part of the logcat is not visible anymore, not even after using filters. where is this entire logcat stored in android-studio. How can I access it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so while I was doing some testing I found the solution. I did it by selecting so it only shows errors, that way I don't see the other messages.

Edit:

To change to error mode select LogCat at the bottom of the screen (or press Alt + 6) and then in the third drop down select the "Error" option.

[image]

Comment: You could also add the information how and where you selected it so that your answer is useful for other users.

Answer (score 0):

This is another idea to store your logcat detail for testing purpose
Try below code

```
public static void extractLogToFile() {

    PackageManager manager = getContext().getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info = null;
    try {
        info = manager.getPackageInfo(getContext().getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e2) {
    }
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    if (!model.startsWith(Build.MANUFACTURER))
        model = Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + model;

    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "your App name" + File.separator;
    File folder = new File(filePath);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    String fileName = "Logcat-" + (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())) + ".txt";
    File file = new File(folder, fileName);

    InputStreamReader reader = null;
    FileWriter writer = null;

    try {
        // For Android 4.0 and earlier, you will get all app's log output,
        // so filter it to
        // mostly limit it to your app's output. In later versions, the
        // filtering isn't needed.
        String cmd = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) ? "logcat -d -v time MyApp:v dalvikvm:v System.err:v *:s" : "logcat -d -v time";

        // get input stream
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        reader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());

        // write output stream
        writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
        writer.write("Android version: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + "\n");
        writer.write("Device: " + model + "\n");
        writer.write("App version: " + (info == null ? "(null)" : info.versionCode) + "\n");

        char[] buffer = new char[10000];
        do {
            int n = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (n == -1)
                break;
            writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
        } while (true);

        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (writer != null)
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            }
        if (reader != null)
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            }
    }
}
```

hope this will work

By this code, you can store logcat detail in your phone storage.
make sure storage permission mentioned in your manifest file as well as implement runtime permission.